# iodine fails its ping test

Tags: dns, tcp, tunnel, iodine

I'm trying to get iodine working on my Ubuntu machine.

The server is working fine, but when it try to establish a connection, and change the route table using the default iodine-client-start script i get the following output

```
==== Creating IP-over-DNS tunnel over local network connection...
==== Local network interface: wlan0
==== Killing existing DNS tunnels...
==== Local address: 198.129.219.148/22
==== Local network: 198.129.216.0/22
==== Local network router: 198.129.216.1
==== DNS servers: 198.129.37.10 198.129.37.11
==== Ping test of local network router and DNS servers...
198.129.216.1 : [0], 96 bytes, 1.18 ms (1.18 avg, 0% loss)
198.129.37.10 : [0], 96 bytes, 1.20 ms (1.20 avg, 0% loss)
198.129.37.11 : [0], 96 bytes, 1.21 ms (1.21 avg, 0% loss)

198.129.216.1 : 1.18
198.129.37.10 : 1.20
198.129.37.11 : 1.21
==== Adding point-to-point route for DNS server 198.129.37.10
RTNETLINK answers: No such process
==== Adding point-to-point route for DNS server 198.129.37.11
RTNETLINK answers: No such process
==== Creating IP-over-DNS tunnel...
Opened dns0
Opened UDP socket
Sending DNS queries for tunnel.mydomain.com to 198.127.36.10
Autodetecting DNS query type (use -T to override).
Using DNS type NULL queries
Version ok, both using protocol v 0x00000502. You are user #0
Setting IP of dns0 to 10.0.0.2
Setting MTU of dns0 to 1130
Server tunnel IP is 10.0.0.1
Testing raw UDP data to the server (skip with -r)
Server is at 173.244.72.158, trying raw login: OK
Sending raw traffic directly to 173.244.72.158
Connection setup complete, transmitting data.
Detaching from terminal...
==== DNS tunnel interface: dns0
==== DNS tunnel remote endpoint: 10.0.0.1
==== Ping test of local router, nameserver, and DNS tunnel...
198.129.216.1 : [0], 96 bytes, 1.29 ms (1.29 avg, 0% loss)
198.129.37.10 : [0], 96 bytes, 1.09 ms (1.09 avg, 0% loss)
198.129.37.11 : [0], 96 bytes, 1.18 ms (1.18 avg, 0% loss)
10.0.0.1      : [0], 96 bytes, 7.10 ms (7.10 avg, 0% loss)

198.129.216.1 : 1.29
198.129.37.10 : 1.09
198.129.37.11 : 1.18
10.0.0.1      : 7.10
==== Setting default route through DNS tunnel...
==== Ping test of local router, nameserver, DNS tunnel, external test host...
198.129.216.1 : [0], 96 bytes, 2.24 ms (2.24 avg, 0% loss)
198.129.37.10 : [0], 96 bytes, 1.17 ms (1.17 avg, 0% loss)
198.129.37.11 : [0], 96 bytes, 1.27 ms (1.27 avg, 0% loss)

198.129.216.1 : 2.24
198.129.37.10 : 1.17
198.129.37.11 : 1.27
10.0.0.1      : -
216.34.181.45 : -
WARNING: Ping test failed.
```

Everything looks find, the connection works, but then I tried to change the route table and the connection breaks. Any idea how to fix it?